# How to run a main after embedded tomcat is run

Tags: java, manifest, maven-tomcat-plugin, embedded-tomcat-7

There is a java webapp with an embedded tomcat 7 that is built with [this instructions](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/executable-war-jar.html) (Using tomcat7-maven-plugin).

this webapp is launching with a jar file like this: `java -jar webapp.jar`

**Question:** How to run a main class after launching this embedded tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to setup your application's entry point. For this you need to configure your main class inside the jar's Manifest file.

Something like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0.1
Created-By: <jdk_version>
Main-Class: fully.qalified.class.name.with.main.method
```

For more details on Manifest, take a look into [this link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

For making this step part of your maven build cycle, you need to make some changes in the mave.jar.plugin. Something like

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
    <mainClass>fully.qalified.class.name.with.main.method</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

The final jar that is created will have your main method as the applications entry point

Comment: but there are these lines in manifest file already:


`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat7RunnerCli`

Comment: then why not append a call to your main method inside the `Tomcat7RunnerCli ` ?

Comment: your'e right, I think I should override that. Isn't there another way to have secondary `Main-Class` in manifest?

Comment: AFAIK, it only seems logical to have a single main method serving as the entry point of the application. Other than that, you can have as many main methods you like !

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. In Eclipse, Right click the project and pick "Run on Server."